# Second countdown inline in a C program

Tags: c, linux

this is a part of my little 'C' program...

```
printf("Time to sleep for the end of process: %d sec\n", getpid() % 10);
```

I would like to come down the seconds, without the line on the terminal changes. Like an animation.

How can i do this in 'C'?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15192441/951890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `\n` with a `\r`, and as long as your numbers are all the same length (number of digits), I believe that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1508589/1971013); on Linux it should work.  But don't print the `'\n'`; do a `fflush(stdout);` instead.

```
printf("%c[2K", 27);
printf("Time to sleep for the end of process: %d sec", getpid() % 10);
fflush(stdout);
```