# Bash place cursor beginning of line

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, command, prompt

How can I set the cursor to the beginning of line in a bash script. It should have the same behavior as pressing Ctrl-a.
I tried something like this `echo -e "\e[H"` but it didn't work.

Here is what I'm trying to do. Let's say I have a command that I want to perform an action on it (doesn't matter what) before executing it. So I associated a Key (using bind -x ) to a function that will perform that action. However, before executing that action, I need to place the cursor to the beginning of that command (as if pressed Ctrl-a)

Comment: `\e[H` (short for `\e[1;1H`) moves the cursor to the first line and first column of the terminal window.

Answer (score 5):

While Deanie's answer of

```
echo -ne "\r"
```

is correct, I found I had to ensure that my hash bang was correct:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

**NOT**

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: Also, check out using printf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192441/update-printf-value-on-same-line-instead-of-new-one

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it just be

`echo -ne "\r"`

Sorry, forgot to suppress the newline.

Comment: It just removes the previous line. Not what I'm searching for.

Comment: @WalidBer "How can I set the cursor to the beginning of line in a bash script"... this is how you can set it to the beginning of the line.  What you want to ask how you set it to the "home" position which is usually the first line and first character space.

Comment: I had to run it with #!/bin/bash and not #!/bin/sh

Answer (score 0):

Let say want bind the `/some/path` to `shift-alt-W` and want move to the beginning of the line:

```
bind '"\eW":"/some/path\C-a"'
```

Pressing the `shift-alt-w` will enter the `/some/path` into the terminal, and the `\C-A` cause to move to the beginning of the line so you can type `cd` before the `/some/path`.

Comment: Is it possible to execute a function binded to my key and then move the cursor to the beginning ? If I try this `bind '"\eW":"my_function\C-a"'`, it just prints  my_function.

Comment: Nevermind, I just found a workaround. `bind '"\key1":"\C-a"'
bind -x '"\key2":"my_function"'
bind '"\eW":"\key1\key2"'. Thanks